# How to derive (extend) recursive connected classes (trees)

Tags: java, derived-class

To display a tree of items I wrote classes that reference themselves:

```
CTree
{
    String name;
    CGroupOfItems[] groups

    CGroupOfItems[] getGroups();
    //... and more getter and setter methods
}

CGroupOfItems
{
    String name;
    CItem[] items;

    CItems[] getItems();
    //... and more getter and setter methods
}


CItem
{
    String name;
    CItem[] childItems;

    CItems[] getChildItems();
    //... and more getter and setter methods
}
```

With this I manage trees like:

```
tree
 -group 1
   - item 1.1
     - item 1.1.1
       - item 1.1.1.1
     - item 1.1.2
   - item 1.2
 - group 2
  - item 2.1
.....
```

Now for some other functions I want to manage trees whose members provide more data:

```
CTreeBig
{
    String name;
    int id;
    String additionalData;
    CGroupOfItemsBig[] groups

    CGroupOfItemsBig[] getGroups();
    //... and more getter and setter methods
}


CGroupOfItemsBig
{
    String name;
    int id;
    String additionalData;
    CItemBig[] items;

    CItemBig[] getItems();
    //... and more getter and setter methods
}


CItemBig
{
    String name;
    int id;
    String additionalData;
    CItemBig[] childItems;

    CItemBig[] getChildItems();
    //... and more getter and setter methods
}
```

Now I would like to extend CTreeBig from CTree.
But this is not possible because I cannot override

```
CGroupOfItems[] getGroups();
```

with:

```
CGroupOfItemsBig[] getGroups();
```

Can anybody give me a hint how I can use Java-Extension for this problem.
At least is is necessary to get an Object CTree from an Object CTreeBig.

Of course i can code this manually but i reality my classes are more complicated an I will have not only two classes CTree but maybe 4 or 5...

Thanks in advance

Gio

Answer (score 0):

You are misusing or misunderstanding inheritance and polymorphism. There is no need to override CGroupOfItems[] getGroups(). You simply implement it in way that is appropriate for CGroupOfItemsBig but the return type is CGroupOfItems because CGroupOfItemsBig "is a" CGroupOfItems. But I suspect there is a deeper issue of understanding the language here. Perhaps this will help: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You described the way I did it up to now and that I wanted to change. I use these structures for an API for some functions. I wanted the user to be able to understand that one function will return CTree the other will return CTreeBig. If I will do as you sugested, the user will always suppose to retrieve the most biggest structures, whose values will not be valid.

Comment: Perhaps I am misunderstanding, but it seems like there is no CTree code that is getting reused for CTreeBig. There doesn't seem to be much of a point to the inheritance.

Comment: For example:I have an API with two functions:

Comment: For example:I have an API with two functions:
public void fct1(CTree smallT);
public void fct2(CTreeBig bigT);
CTree is a part of CTreeBig. For this reason I could use CTreeBig for both functions. But the caller of my functions should be reminded that in fct1 only a small part of CTreeBig-data is used.
==> I want to have a big and a small stucture.
On the other hand the argument of fct1 (smallT) is the result of fct2. The user should be able to retrieve smallT from bigT and then set some individual values...
Here I thought it would be great to do this by inheritance:
CBigTree extends CTree